# Akka HTTP reject with missing header

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have the following method:

```
private def initiateAuth(req: LoginRequest, userAgent: String, deviceId: String) = {
    extractClientIP { clientIp =>
      extractRequestContext { implicit ctx =>
        if (clientIp.toOption.isEmpty) reject(Rejections.validationRejection("abc"))
        val xForwardedFor = clientIp.toOption.map(_.getHostAddress).get
        mapToResponse(userAuthenticator.auth(req.username, req.password, deviceId, xForwardedFor, userAgent))
      }
    }
}
```

What is really strange is `Rejections.validationRejection("abc")` works but when I use `Rejections.missingHeader("abc")` I get an error:

[image]

What is different between the two? I am confused ecause MissingHeaderRejection implements Rejection, so why the type mismatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your if statement  when clientIp option is empty the result of *if* gets ignored. I'd better use pattern matching or *if - else* expression